# Why does Mamoru Oshii include a basset hound in his movies?

Tags: mamoru-oshii

The title really says it all. The basset hound is almost always there in Oshii's signature long musical interludes (Ghost in the Shell I & II, Patlabor II ... etc). Does the basset hound have a special meaning to Oshii?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a ["Japanorama" interview with Jonathan Ross](http://www.animeuknews.net/news/832/jonathan-ross-tv-interview-with-mamoru-oshii) he mentions that he thinks that he's a reincarnated basset hound. He's got an affinity for that particular breed of dog so he uses it a lot in his movies.